# Request ongoing host permissions in a manifest v3 browser extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, browser-extension

I have a manifest v3 browser extension that has a content script, which I want to be automatically injected into certain pages, without the user explicitly interacting with the extension each time they open it. Normally this would require host permissions, which I want to avoid. Is it possible to have an extension that initially starts with no host permissions, then when the user interacts with the extension and accepts the permissions, it permanently gains host permissions to that page? If so, how can I do this?

I am aware of `optional_host_permissions` in the manifest, so I realise that an extension can request host permissions, but my understanding is that these increased permissions are only temporary. If this is true, then `optional_host_permissions` won't suit my need. Also, the requesting can only be done after the user interacts with the extension, but I don't want the user to have to manually click the action button each time they want to enable my extension, it should start automatically.

Comment: It's not temporary. Note that you need to use [permissions API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/permissions/) one time to actually grant it.

Comment: Okay that's good, but I still need a user interaction (ie clicking on my action) before I can request the permissions, which doesn't suit my use case

Comment: Your question says "when the user interacts with the extension and accepts the permissions" and this is exactly what the permissions API is for.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between allowing all and allowing individually without UI.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm happy to have to request permissions the first time, when the user interacts with my extension. However, I don't want them to have to interact the subsequent times. As far as I can tell, even if I gain the optional host permissions, I can't statically inject a content script, I must always do that in response to user interaction. Am I wrong?

Comment: Wrong. You can use chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts once you get the permissions

Comment: Okay, I'll happily accept this as an answer then if you write one up